# rails3 callback for nested record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback, after-create

On creation of a record, I am attempting, on creation of parent class Quote, to set default values for related class Optionvolume

```
class Optionvolume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :quote

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :options

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  has_many :optionvolumes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :options, through: :optionvolumes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :optionvolumes, :allow_destroy => true    

  after_create :set_optionvolumes

  private
    def set_optionvolumes
      @options = Option.where(['options_tasks.task_id = ?', self.task_id]).joins(:tasks)
      @options.each do |option|
        self.optionvolumes.create(:quantity => '0', :option_id => option.id)
      end
    end
```

However, I am generating the records partially.
While the @options generates, for the given case 10 results (correctly).  However, only the the quantity field is being generated (as is the quote_id rails handles via the context).  the option_id remains blank

```
Optionvolume id: 111, quote_id: 27, quantity: 0, created_at: [...]
Optionvolume id: 112, quote_id: 27, quantity: 0, created_at: [...]
```

etc...
The server is even indicating that it should be handling the data

```
INSERT INTO "optionvolumes" ("option_id", "quote_id", "created_at", "quantity", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["option_id", 15], ["quote_id", 38], ["created_at", Tue, 13 Aug 2013 11:20:07 UTC +00:00], ["quantity", 0], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Aug 2013 11:20:07 UTC +00:00]]
INSERT INTO "optionvolumes" ("option_id", "quote_id", "created_at", "quantity", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["option_id", 16], ["quote_id", 38], ["created_at", Tue, 13 Aug 2013 11:20:07 UTC +00:00], ["quantity", 0], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Aug 2013 11:20:07 UTC +00:00]]
```

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the server log is simply not showing the option_id being saved, but the application is handling it.  A

```
<%= ff.object.inspect %>
```

command shows it's there.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html  was quite helpful in this regard.